# Django debug with Geany

Tags: python, django, debugging, geany

Today I changed IDE from Gedit to Geany.
I want to debug my django project, but don't know how.
My settings in debug tab:
**Target:** /path/to/manage.py
**Command line arguments:** runserver --noreload
**Env variables:**
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = settings
PYTHONPATH = *print sys.path*

When I try to run server, I got an error: **Error loading file**

Google doesn't help...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is `Target` literally `/path/to/manage.py`?

Comment: Oh, of course not. I'm not that dumb :)